# Groovy calcaution is same as javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, groovy

What was wrong `Groovy` calculation in my program?

```
public class GroovyRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new GroovyShell().parse(new File("hello.groovy")).invokeMethod("show", null);
    }
}
```

hello.groovy

```
def show() {
    float a = 0.1;
    float c = 0.1;
    float d = 0.2;
    if(a + c == d) {
        println "Equal"
    } else {
        println "Not Equal"
    }
}

The result is `Equal`
```

When I change the value of `c` and `d` variable as below. The result is `Not Equal`

hello.groovy

```
def show() {
    float a = 0.1;
    float c = 0.2;
    float d = 0.3;
    if(a + c == d) {
        println "Equal"
    } else {
        println "Not Equal"
    }
}
```

I decided to use `Groovy` as I would like to avoid the floating point calculation of `Javascript` engine.
Groovy calculation is as `Javascript`?

Comment: @Cerbrus, Actually, I would like to configure calculation process as `script` file. But, I requirement is `don't use javascript calculation`. How can I use  `java` calculation as scipt  file configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
  float a = 0.1;
  float c = 0.2;
  float d = 0.3;
```

Use:

```
  def a = 0.1
  def c = 0.2
  def d = 0.3
```

Groovy will handle with automatically and provide the correct result.